# ViewPager with viewmodel and live data , all 6 tabs data is replaced by last tab data

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am working on a `ViewPager` with 6 `tabs` where it has only one fragment `TimesListFragment`

Depending on the arguments passed to `TimesListFragment` it calls api eg; science , technology, travel etc

I have followed Google's `GithubBrowserSample` for my app

I have `TimesListFragment` -> `TimesViewModel` -> `TimesRepository`

There are 6 tabs , when I hit the api all the tabs show the same result which if of the last `argument`

**StoriesPagerAdapter.kt**

```
class StoriesPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager?)
    :FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager){
    private val sections= arrayListOf("science","technology","business","world","movies","travel")
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return TimesListFragment.newInstance(sections[position])
    }
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return sections.size
    }
    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return sections[position]
    }
}
```

**issue : all tabs shows data of `travel` arguments**

**TimesViewModel**

```
class TimesViewModel @Inject constructor(private val timesRepository: TimesRepository) :
        ViewModel() {
    lateinit var data: LiveData<Resource<TimesStoriesResponse>>
    fun fetchStories(section:String): LiveData<Resource<TimesStoriesResponse>> {
        data = timesRepository.loadStories(section)
        return data
    }
}
```

**TimesRepository.kt**

```
class TimesRepository @Inject constructor(private val apiService: ApiService,
                                          private val timesDao: TimesDao,
                                          private val appExecutors: AppExecutors) {

    private val repoListRateLimit = RateLimiter<String>(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)

    fun loadStories(section:String): LiveData<Resource<TimesStoriesResponse>> {
        return object : NetworkBoundResource<TimesStoriesResponse, TimesStoriesResponse>(appExecutors) {
            override fun saveCallResult(item: TimesStoriesResponse) {
                timesDao.insert(item)
            }

            override fun shouldFetch(data: TimesStoriesResponse?): Boolean {
                return data == null  || repoListRateLimit.shouldFetch(section)
            }

            override fun loadFromDb() = timesDao.load()

            override fun createCall() = apiService.getTopStories(section,ConfigConstant.TIMES_KEY)

            override fun onFetchFailed() {
                repoListRateLimit.reset(section)
            }
        }.asLiveData()
    }
```

**ApiService.kt**

```
interface ApiService {
    @GET("svc/topstories/v2/{section}.json?")
    fun getTopStories(@Path ("section") section:String,@Query("api-key") apiKey:String)
            :LiveData<ApiResponse<TimesStoriesResponse>>
}
```

**TimesListFragment.kt**

```
private fun initViewModel() {

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(section,TimesViewModel::class.java)

    }

    private fun initData() {
        viewModel?.fetchStories(section)?.observe(this, Observer {

            when (it?.status) {

                Status.LOADING -> {
                    showLoading(true)
                    showError(false,null)
                }


                Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    showLoading(false)
                    showError(false,null)
                    showSuccessData(it.data)
                }

                Status.ERROR -> {
                    showLoading(false)
                    showError(true,it.message)
                }

            }
        })
    }
```

**note : both methods are called in onViewCreated() of `TimesListFragmnet`**

Comment: Can you post the code of ApiService?

Comment: posted ApiService code...

Comment: Yeah, i had the same issue because, `ViewPager` caches one page to and fro by default. So, one solution is to manage whether your **fragment** is visible inside `ViewPager` using `setUserVisibleHint()` method in your `ViewPager` fragments.

Comment: @Jeel Vankhede : Didn't made any difference . I think it has to do with LiveData

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This should be happening due to your `ViewModel`.

Typically, there's one `ViewModel` per `Activity` or `Fragment`, due to the way a `ViewModel` is designed to work. One of the major benefits in using a `ViewModel` is that it's lifecycle is completely separate from the lifecycle of your `Fragment`, therefore, your `Fragment` can be destroyed and recreated multiple times and you'll still be able to restore current data that's stored in your `ViewModel`.

Therefore, this means that with the typical code to fetch the `ViewModel` from the `ViewModelProviders`, you'll be fetching the exact same `ViewModel`.

Typically, this won't cause a problem, but in your `ViewPager`, you're reusing the same `TimesListFragment` which is *most likely* calling up the same `ViewModel`, therefore causing each fragment to show the same data.

The solution for this is to use:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(KEY, TimesViewModel::class.java)
```

Note the KEY which is used to differentiate between the ViewModels that needs to be fetched. So by using the positions in the `ViewPager` as a unique key, you should be able to have a unique `ViewModel` for each `TimesListFragment`.

Comment: When every time I call TimesListFragment its onCreate() is called , this means every time new instance of fragment is created , so new instance of TimesViewModel . Is I am right ?

Comment: Nope, the way `ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TimesViewModel::class.java)` works is that it'll create a new instance of `TimesViewModel` if it doesn't exist. But if it already exists, then it'll return the existing one. Therefore, all 6 `TimesListFragment` would be using the same `ViewModel`. But if you use `ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(KEY, TimesViewModel::class.java)` where you can specify a `KEY`, then you'll be able to create a unique `ViewModel` that belongs to each `TimesListFragment`.

Comment: tried passing tab title(science , technology etc) in KEY to differentiate ViewModel , didn't worked :( . viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(section,TimesViewModel::class.java)

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please show the parts of the code where you fetch the ViewModel in TimesListFragment.

Comment: please see my post

Comment: I found the problem . The values are inserted to the database are replaced by the last api data and that is shown in the UI . Now figuring out how to solved this

Comment: not workign for me, I'm having 2 different fragments (which inherits from the same parent) who live inside FragmentPagerAdapter, in each of these fragments I instantiate view model (same viewmodel class but 2 instances).

chatRoomViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get("KEY1", ChatRoomViewModel.class);

chatRoomViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get("KEY2", ChatRoomViewModel.class);

even though im changing data in fragment 1, the observer method in fragment2 is called, is there a way toa void it?

Comment: @karthikkolanji how did you fix this?? I tried passing the title as the Key and it's not working

Comment: @ hushed_voice -> it was room issue .. refer my project https://github.com/karthikkolanji/new_york_times

Comment: For me this issue is coming if I am using by viewModels({requireParentFragment()}) from ktx, there is no way to pass key. All the fragments are replaced with last fragment

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the `ViewPager` not to load pages that are currently not showing. By default it loads at least one page to the left and one to the right, I think.